# Did not get any data from server using socket programming in phone gap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am implementing socket programming in android using  phonegap. But i am not getting any data from server.Actually  my PC is am consumer as  producer .So i am hitting only to my ip address but i am not getting any error .But did not get any response .
Please help me . ...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>websocket-android-phonegap</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/websocket.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>


  </body>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // new socket
    alert("Start");
    //var socket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.12.171:8101/');
    var socket = new WebSocket('http://192.168.12.171:8001');

    // push a message after the connection is established.
    socket.onopen = function() {
    alert("Open")
        //socket.send('Hello World')
    };

    // alerts message pushed from server
    socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
    };

    // alert close event
    socket.onclose = function() {
        alert('closed');
    };

    // now, close the connection after 10 secons. (funny!)
    /*setInterval(function() {
        socket.close();
    }, 10000); */
</script>  

</html>
```

---

```
(function() {

    // window object
    var global = window;

    // WebSocket Object. All listener methods are cleaned up!
    var WebSocket = global.WebSocket = function(url) {
    alert("---")
        // get a new websocket object from factory (check com.strumsoft.websocket.WebSocketFactory.java)
        this.socket = WebSocketFactory.getInstance(url);
        // store in registry
        if(this.socket) {
            WebSocket.store[this.socket.getId()] = this;
        } else {
            throw new Error('Websocket instantiation failed! Address might be wrong.');
        }
    };

    // storage to hold websocket object for later invokation of event methods
    WebSocket.store = {};

    // static event methods to call event methods on target websocket objects
    WebSocket.onmessage = function (evt) {
        WebSocket.store[evt._target]['onmessage'].call(global, evt);
    }   

    WebSocket.onopen = function (evt) {
        WebSocket.store[evt._target]['onopen'].call(global, evt);
    }

    WebSocket.onclose = function (evt) {
        WebSocket.store[evt._target]['onclose'].call(global, evt);
    }

    WebSocket.onerror = function (evt) {
        WebSocket.store[evt._target]['onerror'].call(global, evt);
    }

    // instance event methods
    WebSocket.prototype.send = function(data) {
        this.socket.send(data);
    }

    WebSocket.prototype.close = function() {
        this.socket.close();
    }

    WebSocket.prototype.getReadyState = function() {
        this.socket.getReadyState();
    }
    ///////////// Must be overloaded
    WebSocket.prototype.onopen = function(){
        throw new Error('onopen not implemented.');
    };

    // alerts message pushed from server
    WebSocket.prototype.onmessage = function(msg){
        throw new Error('onmessage not implemented.');
    };

    // alerts message pushed from server
    WebSocket.prototype.onerror = function(msg){
        throw new Error('onerror not implemented.');
    };

    // alert close event
    WebSocket.prototype.onclose = function(){
        throw new Error('onclose not implemented.');
    };
})();
```

Comment: can you please provide any link ...

Answer (score 0):

I use socket.io with phonegap.
You can upload the demo project to nodejitsu.